# Memory attributes of kernel virtual address in arm64

Tags: c, linux, virtual-memory, arm64

I am trying to read the memory attributes of a virtual memory address allocated via kmalloc, inside a kernel module.

Doing a manual page table walk using apis provided in arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable.h.

Following is the code.

```
{
    unsigned int attr;
    pud_t *pud;
    pmd_t *pmd;
    pte_t *pte; 
    pgd_t *pgd, *swapper_pgd;
    struct page *pg = phys_to_page(read_sysreg(ttbr1_el1));

    swapper_pgd = (pgd_t*) kmap(pg);
    pgd = pgd_offset_raw(swapper_pgd, (uint64_t)buf);
    pgd_ptr = (pgd_t *)kmap(pgd_page(*pgd));
    if(!pgd)
       return 0;
    kunmap(pg);
    pg = phys_to_page(pud_offset_phys(pgd, (uint64_t)buf));
    pud = (pud_t *)kmap(pg);
    if(!pud)
      return 0;
    kunmap(pg);
    pg = phys_to_page(pmd_offset_phys(pud, (uint64_t)buf));
    pmd = (pmd_t *)kmap(pg);
    if(!pmd)
       return 0;
    kunmap(pg);
    pg = phys_to_page(pte_offset_phys(pmd, (uint64_t)buf));
    pte = (pte_t *)kmap(pg);
    if(!pte)
       return 0;
    attr = PTE_ATTRINDX_MASK & pte_val(*pte);
    kunmap(pg);
    return attr;
}
```

Can I rely on the memory attribute value I get from this code?